# Как можно избавиться от ошибки из-за пустых ячеек Excel файла?

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, excel

Код:

```
def find_cell_next_to_val(filename, val, **kwargs):
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, header=None, dtype=str, **kwargs)
    df = df.apply(lambda col: col.str.strip())
    rows, cols = np.where(df == str(val).strip())
    if len(rows) == 0:
        return None
    row, col = rows[0], cols[0]
    if col + 1 > df.shape[1]:
        return None
    col_idx = df.iloc[row, col+1:].first_valid_index()
    try:
        return df.iat[row, col_idx]
    except KeyError:
        return None
```

читает данные файлов Excel, однако если некоторая интересующая нас ячейка ссылается на пустоту то эта функция возвращает ошибку:

> ValueError: iAt based indexing can only have integer indexers

Как можно избавиться от этой ошибки?

[Ссылка](https://yadi.sk/i/6DAvJVbc7bOoyQ) на файл с исходными данными.

Comment: можете выложить файл, который позволит воспроизвести ошибку?

Comment: Никто кроме тебя не помогает мне тут :D. Сейчас выложу. В этом файле искомая ячейкая пустая и все ячейки правее нее тоже пустые, мне кажется в этом дело

Comment: [ссылка](https://yadi.sk/i/6DAvJVbc7bOoyQ) лист дефектный акт

Comment: а что ищем в этом файле? какие параметры вызова функции приводят к ошибке?

Comment: 'invnumber = find_cell_next_to_val(filename, "инв.№", sheet_name="Дефектный акт")'

Comment: у меня ошибка не воспроизводится - после выполнения `invnumber --> None`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
def find_cell_next_to_val(filename, val, **kwargs):
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, header=None, dtype=str, **kwargs)
    df = df.apply(lambda col: col.str.strip())
    rows, cols = np.where(df == str(val).strip())
    if len(rows) == 0:
        return None
    row, col = rows[0], cols[0]
    if col + 1 > df.shape[1]:
        return None
    col_idx = df.iloc[row, col+1:].first_valid_index()
    try:
        return df.iat[row, col_idx]
    except (KeyError, ValueError):
        return None
```

Comment: Отлично, работает. Если пустая возвращает None, а не прекращает выполнение кода ошибкой. Спасибо большое